# Opposite to 'verbatim' - like, but not exactly, 'paraphrased'

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that is pretty much opposite to 'verbatim', but not 'paraphrased.' A word that means capturing the idea of something but not the exact phrasing.

I'm typing notes from an event I attended, and I want to differentiate between exact (or near-exact quotations,) and notes I'm making right now based on my memory - e.g. my current impression of what was said originally. So I'm not exactly paraphrasing in that I'm not rewording a specific quote. I've a section of my notes dedicated to verbatim quotes, and a section dedicated to [missing word].

I guess I could go with 'Impressions' or something but it's also not quite right.

Comment: Perhaps *précis*?

Comment: Still sounds like paraphrasing, to me. How do you distinguish what you are trying to describe from paraphrasing? Paraphrasing is saying the same thing, or similar, but not in the same words.

Comment: @Drew: The OP appears to believe that "paraphrasing" implies that you *have* the exact quotation, but are intentionally rewording it.

Comment: @ruakh: Then the OP should look up *paraphrase* in a dictionary.

Comment: @Drew Thanks, I looked up the meaning in the dictionary. I know what it means, but it didn't feel right to me. These are notes _on_, not _of_ an event. They are my current thoughts, not the original source's thoughts. Perhaps it’s a bit nuanced, but ‘paraphrase’ still feels too specific and less abstract than what I’m actually doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several words (check synonyms of *summary*) but perhaps ***abstract*** satisfies your requirements best.

ODO:

> ***[abstract](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/abstract)***
> *NOUN*
>
> **1** A summary of the contents of a book, article, or speech:
>
> ‘an abstract of her speech’
>
> **Synonyms**
>
> summary, synopsis, precis, résumé, outline, recapitulation,
> abridgement, condensation, digest, summation

Comment: You might want to consider adding the definition of *abstract* as a transitive verb meaning "to make a summary or abstract of" (M-W). Just a thought. Nice to see you approaching 10k.

Comment: @1006a _synopsis_ was my first thought but thought _abstract_ is somehow better. It's strange how we move away from first thoughts sometimes.

Comment: @RichardKayser Thanks. I know you are not far behind (should we call you Richard Express?). I stuck to the noun form because it goes with "impressions" suggested by the OP.

Comment: I get it. The question just made me think verbs: quote verbatim, paraphrase, abstract, ... It's all good.

Comment: I actually meant *summary*; you were editing as I was commenting. The OP's example sentence seems to me to call for a mass noun, which would make summary fit a bit better, though any of your suggestions could work. ("*I've a section of my notes dedicated to verbatim quotes, and a section dedicated to **summary***.")

Comment: Well, I thought _summary_ is too broad for the OP's context. It still works, I agree.

Comment: Thanks people. These are helpful suggestions that close in on what I'm aiming for. _Summary_ and _synopsis_ are such normal words that I'm annoyed I couldn't think of them myself. _Abstract_ is probably what I'll go for. I normally use it as a verb or adjective so didn’t think of in that sense earlier.

Answer (score 2):

I think the correct word actually **is** *paraphrasing*. You seem to feel that "paraphrasing" necessarily implies that you have the exact quote available to you, but are intentionally choosing to use different words; but that's not in fact the case. Quoting from http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/paraphrase:

> We paraphrase all the time. When you tell a friend what someone else has said, you're almost always paraphrasing, since you're not repeating the exact words. If you go to hear a talk, you might paraphrase the speaker's main points afterward for your friends.

Answer (score 2):

I might call the rest of your notes the *gist* of what was said.

> [***gist***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/gist) - The substance or general meaning of a speech or text

*Paraphrase* seems to imply rewording or improvement rather than simple distillation of the original.  Given the amount of sarcastic, pillorying paraphrasing done these days, I'm also leery of using that term.

Answer (score 0):

Paraphrasing is a good one, but it didn't quite fit what I was looking for. This is the [paraphrased] sentence I ended up going with:

> I then called John, who said words to the effect of, “if you have to cancel your appointment, you will be charged £50", implying that there was no recourse for any reason. I later found this out to be false.